# Compare multidimensional array with inner array for next key

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, compare

```
 Array
(
    [6000] => Array
        (
            [2225] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Värmesystem
                            [Value] => AC/ACC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Volym
                            [Value] => 0,5 Liter
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Fordontrustning
                            [Value] => Med Ac
                        )

                )

            [2224] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Värmesystem
                            [Value] => AC/ACC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Volym
                            [Value] => 0,5 Liter
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Fordontrustning
                            [Value] => Med Coll
                        )

                )

        )

    [18000] => Array
        (
            [2214] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Värmesystem
                            [Value] => AC/ACC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Volym
                            [Value] => 0,5 Liter
                        )
                     [2] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Fordontrustning
                            [Value] => Med Ac
                        )

                )

            [2213] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Värmesystem
                            [Value] => AC/ACC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Volym
                            [Value] => 0,5 Liter
                        )
                     [2] => Array
                        (
                            [MarketCode] => SE
                            [Type] => Fordontrustning
                            [Value] => Med Coll
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

how to compare in given array?

I mean how to compare index of 2225 to 2224 for key value 6000

I have tried to compare like multidemnsional array but it doesn't work,

**desire OUTPUT**

```
[2] => Array
                    (
                        [MarketCode] => SE
                        [Type] => Fordontrustning
                        [Value] => Med Ac
                    )
                    Because it is different from [2224] => Array of [2] => Array
                    (
                        [MarketCode] => SE
                        [Type] => Fordontrustning
                        [Value] => Med Coll
                    )
```

Till i have try like this

```
                           foreach($miles as $m => $k){
                               foreach($miles as $key => $val){
                                   if($key != $m){
                                    for($j=0;$j<=count($k);$j++){
                                        for($x=0;$x<=count($val);$x++){

                                            if($k[$j][0]!=$val[$x][0] && !empty($k[$j]) && !empty($val[$x])){
                                                echo "start";
                                                print_r($k[$j]);
                                            echo ".......<br>";
                                            print_r($val[$x]);    
                                            echo "end";
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                        }
```

Please help me if still have any another way with inbuilt php function ?

Comment: What do you mean by that comparison? Just show us what result you want to get.

Comment: What is your goal? I mean, besides comparsion. Can you explain better please?

Comment: compare all 3 index from 0 index of 2225 to 2213's 0,1,2,4 and so on with 1 index of 2225 to 2213's 0,1,2,4. hope now it is clear

Comment: With your example, we can see that `$data[6000][2225][2]` is different to `$data[6000][2224][2]`. When there is a difference, what should happen? Do you keep one value and discard the other? How do you decide?